# DHCP MAC reservations + DHCP in the same time

Tags: configuration, dhcp

I wanted to make DHCP reservations for my IP phones, using this configuration, but the problem is now, that I cant use DHCP to dynamically assign address to other devices and I have no idea to to make this work both in the same time.

```
dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff via eth0 network 10.10.10.0/24 no free leases
```

dhcp conf

```
    option domain-name "";
    option domain-name-servers 10.10.10.1;
    option tftp-server-name "10.10.10.1";
    default-lease-time 28800;
    max-lease-time 43200;

    subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
           option routers 10.10.10.1;
    }

    host iptel1 {
        hardware ethernet ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
        fixed-address 10.10.10.11;
    }

    host iptel2 {
        hardware ethernet ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
        fixed-address 10.10.10.12;
    }

    host iptel3 {
        hardware ethernet ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
        fixed-address 10.10.10.13;
    }

    host iptel4 {
        hardware ethernet ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
        fixed-address 10.10.10.14;
    }

    host iptel5 {
        hardware ethernet ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
        fixed-address 10.10.10.15;
    }
    host iptel6 {
        hardware ethernet ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
        fixed-address 10.10.10.16;
    }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried looking into `dnsmasq`. For small or home networks it's really great with an easy configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf
```

Try with this configuration example

```
subnet 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option domain-name "domain.net";
  option broadcast-address 192.168.100.255;
  option routers 192.168.100.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.100.1, 8.8.8.8;

  # Define the scopes for this DHCP pool

  pool {
   range 192.168.100.2 192.168.100.200;
   # static reserve = 192.168.100.201 - 192.168.100.254
  }
  host static-custid {
   hardware ethernet 00:01:02:03:04:05;
   fixed-address 192.168.100.205;
  }
  host static-custid {
   hardware ethernet 00:01:02:03:04:06;
   fixed address 192.168.100.206;
  }
}
```

Note: You `dhcp` pool is from `192.168.100.2 192.168.100.200`, your netmask is `255.255.255.0` your router is on address `192.168.100.1`. DHCP server will always assign Host with mac address `00:01:02:03:04:05` ip `192.168.100.205`, with mac `00:01:02:03:04:06` ip `192.168.100.206`. But if come host with mac `00:01:02:03:04:08` server will assign next free ip address from pool.

P.S. After change of config, restart dhcp server.